# how to use dsp tags with jsonlib

Tags: json, taglib, atg

i want to output some data within jsp using json format. i am trying to use json-taglib for same. Can someone please help me with combining jsontaglib with atg dsp tags? below is the code.

```
<%@ taglib prefix="json" uri="http://www.atg.com/taglibs/json" %>
<dsp:page>
<json:property name="image" value="<dsp:valueof param='mysite.image'/>" />
<json:property name="name" value='<dsp:valueof param="mysite.name"/>' />
</json:object>`
</dsp:page>
```

But the code above is just printing my dsp:valueof tags instead of it's value. Why?

Also, i need to use foreach droplet to print out a nested json array.Can someone help me with an example on how can i achieve that?
TIA

Answer (score 0):

Since you are explicitly importing the `json` taglib, you might need to import the `dsp` taglib too?

Apart from that you are missing a starting tag for your `<json:object>`, the rest appears to be correct.

An example of using the `ForEach` droplet to generate a nested `json` array is as follow:

```
<dsp:importbean bean="/atg/dynamo/droplet/ForEach" />
<dsp:page>
    <json:object>
        <json:property name="image">
            <dsp:valueof param="mysite.image" />
        </json:property>
        <json:property name="name">
            <dsp:valueof param="mysite.name" />
        </json:property>
        <json:array>
            <dsp:droplet name="/atg/dynamo/droplet/ForEach">
                <dsp:param name="array" param="SomeParameterPassedToThisDroplet" />
                <dsp:oparam name="output">
                    <json:object>
                        <json:property name="element.propertyname">
                            <dsp:valueof param="element.propertyvalue" />
                        </json:property>
                    </json:object>
                </dsp:oparam>
            </dsp:droplet>
        </json:array>
    </json:object>
</dsp:page>
```